# Как вывести html тэги из объекта в js?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой объект, для смены языка на сайте:

```
var arrLang = {
'en': {
'text': 'my name is ivan'
},
'ru': {
'text': 'меня зовут иван'
}
}
```

на странице текст выводится в одну строку, нужно отформатировать текст, где-то жирным выделить, переносы проставить, например `'text': 'меня зовут br иван'` - естественно не сработает. А текста на странице прям достаточно.
Как же это сделать?

Comment: почему не сработает? Пишите в `innerHTML` и все сработает.

Comment: $(this).empty().append($.parseHTML(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')])); эта строчка помогла. Учитывая скрипт переключения, сохранения языка.

Answer (score 1):

```
text: "меня зовут <br> иван"
...
...
ЧТОТО.innerHTML = arrLang.ru.text
```